Why is the callback not happening?
I'm trying to update the value of showErrorMode with a callback passed to my Canvas composable, but the callback doesn't happen. I need this to show an adequate error to my user.
fun CameraPreview(
    viewModel: DcodeViewModel,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    controller: LifecycleCameraController,
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    val isTorchOn by viewModel.isTorchOn.collectAsState()
    val uiBoxes by viewModel.currentUiBoxes.collectAsState()
    val foundDcode by viewModel.foundDcode.collectAsState()
    val currentHex by viewModel.currentHex.collectAsState()
    var showErrorMode by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Log.d(UI_TEST, "ERROR MODE : $showErrorMode") <-- shows zeros at the beginning of analysis 
    val error by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            when (showErrorMode) {
                1 -> {
                    Log.d(UI_TEST,"Phone is too close to Dcode")
                    "Phone is too close to Dcode"
                }
                2 -> {
                    Log.d(UI_TEST,"Phone is too far from Dcode")
                    "Phone is too far from Dcode"
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d(UI_TEST,"Phone is in a good position")
                    null
                }
            }
        }
    }
...

... 
 foundDcode?.let { dcode ->
                DetectionCanvas(listOf(dcode)) { newMode ->
                    Log.d(UI_TEST, "SHOULD BE UPDATED TO $newMode") <- THIS ISNT CALLED
                    showErrorMode = newMode
                }
            } ?: DetectionCanvas(uiBoxes){}
...

@Composable
private fun DetectionCanvas(uiBoxes: List<UiBox>, setErrorMode: (Int) -> Unit ) {
    val boxClosestToCenter = uiBoxes.firstOrNull { it.isClosestToCenter }
    val remainingBoxes = uiBoxes.filterNot { it.isClosestToCenter }

    Box {
        boxClosestToCenter?.let { mainUiBox ->
            if (mainUiBox.isTooBig) {
                Log.d(UI_TEST,"TOO BIG") <- THIS IS CALLED
                setErrorMode(1)
            } else if (mainUiBox.isTooSmall) {
                Log.d(UI_TEST,"TOO SMALL")
                setErrorMode(2)
            } else {
                Log.d(UI_TEST,"NORMAL")
                setErrorMode(0)
            }

            Canvas(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .background(Color.Transparent)
                    .zIndex(2f)
            ) {
                val color = Color.Red
                val stroke = Stroke(width = 6f)
                drawRect(
                    color = color,
                    topLeft = boxClosestToCenter.start,
                    size = boxClosestToCenter.size,
                    style = stroke
                )
            }
        }

        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .background(Color.Transparent)
        ) {
            remainingBoxes.forEach { uiBox ->
                val color = Color.Yellow
                val stroke = Stroke(width = 3f)
                drawRect(
                    color = color,
                    topLeft = uiBox.start,
                    size = uiBox.size,
                    style = stroke
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

All the size checks in UiBox are correct. I have no idea what might be wrong since this approach worked for me in multiple composables. Is this some kind of scope issue ?

Have you added log inside derivedStateOf to check if that is triggered or not?

I added logging inside the derivedStateOf block, but since the function that updates showErrorMode isn't being called, the derived state value isn't being recalculated.

After some more tests I came to conclusions that it must be something related to nullscoped actions not causing recomposition, but i still dont know how to fix it

So I create a mock up on this problem and i found the problem
using StateFlow might not updated, so i use SharedFlow with no cache
and it's working
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _uiBoxes = MutableSharedFlow<List<UiBox>>(replay = 0)
    val uiBoxes  = _uiBoxes.asSharedFlow()
    private var roundRobin = false

    fun mock() {
        val newBoxes = if (roundRobin) {
            listOf(
                UiBox(isTooBig = true, isClosestToCenter = true),
                UiBox(isTooSmall = true, start = Offset(10f, 40f)),
                UiBox(isTooSmall = false, start = Offset(10f, 80f))
            )
        } else {
            listOf(
                UiBox(isTooSmall = true, isClosestToCenter = true),
                UiBox(isTooSmall = true, start = Offset(40f, 40f))
            )
        }
        roundRobin = !roundRobin
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _uiBoxes.emit(newBoxes)
        }
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview2() {
    val viewmodel = TestViewModel()
    val uiBoxes by viewmodel.uiBoxes.collectAsState(listOf())
    var showErrorMode by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }


    val error by remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            when (showErrorMode) {
                1 -> {
                    Log.d("UI_TEST", "Phone is too close to Dcode")
                    "Phone is too close to Dcode"
                }
                2 -> {
                    Log.d("UI_TEST", "Phone is too far from Dcode")
                    "Phone is too far from Dcode"
                }
                else -> {
                    Log.d("UI_TEST", "Phone is in a good position")
                    null
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        Button(onClick = {
            viewmodel.mock()
        }) {
            Text(text = "Test")
        }
        error?.let { Text(text = it) }

        DetectionCanvas(uiBoxes = uiBoxes) {
            showErrorMode = it
        }
    }
}


i assume it might be due to caching in StateFlow so that why is not updating.
Hope this helpful.
